# VS Code showing me "Error loading workspace: found module "main.go" twice in the workspace"

Tags: go, module, compiler-errors, vscode-extensions

I am using the [primary GO extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go).

I use VS code a lot, now I'm learning GO lang.
And when I open VS Code every time I'm getting this:

```
Error loading workspace: found module "main.go" twice in the workspace.
```

While running the code it's giving the right output.
I don't know how to fix this.
Anybody, help me with this error.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to open in VSCode only one folder with its own `go.mod` project.

A workspace with multiple `go.mod`/project should be supported [with 1.18](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18#go-command)

> The `go` command now supports a "Workspace" mode.
>
> If a `go.work` file is found in the working directory or a parent directory, or one is specified using the `-workfile` flag, it will put the go command into workspace mode.
> In workspace mode, the `go.work` file will be used to determine the set of main modules used as the roots for module resolution, instead of using the normally-found `go.mod` file to specify the single main module.

As described in "[How to make VScode Go work in a Multi-Module Repo](https://varunksaini.com/vscode-multimodule-repo/)" from **Varun Kumar**, this used to work:

> If you want to work with all the nested modules in a single workspace, there is an opt-in module feature that allows to work with multiple modules without creating workspace folders for each module. Set this in your settings -
>
> ```
> "build.experimentalWorkspaceModule": true
> ```

But as [per september 2022 is deprecated](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52897).
See more at [`gopls` documentation "Setting up your workspace"](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md).

Comment: doesn't it work only for go 1.18?

Comment: @AdilAkhmetov yes, I do mention 1.18 in my answer. You do need indeed Go .18 or more recent.

Comment: It's deprecated now.

Comment: @musicformellons Yes, from [gopls 0.11.0, Jan. 2023](https://github.com/NetBSD/pkgsrc/commit/4e10421ec3a44a38673510f7c5a3ec60d5a26d01). Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

- you have only one project is open in vscode
- your GOPATH is set correctly
- you don't have 2 go.mod in the same project
- you installed the recommended tools(vscode) for golang